# Can't use %F with std::get_time()

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out why I can't use `std::get_time()` with the `%F` format specifier in C++11. It's not working for me in clang 3.8.0 or gcc 5.4.0. I'm under the impression that the `%F` format specifier to `strftime()` is part of the C++11 standard, and `std::get_time()` uses `strftime()` format specifiers? Am I incorrect, or is there something wrong with my code here?

```
#include <cstdio>   // printf()
#include <ctime>    // std::tm
#include <cstring>  // memcpy()
#include <sstream>  // std::istringstream
#include <iomanip>  // std::get_time()

void print(const std::istringstream& iss, const struct tm& time_struct)
{
    if(! iss.fail())
    {
        printf("struct tm {\n"
                "    tm_sec   = %d\n"
                "    tm_min   = %d\n"
                "    tm_hour  = %d\n"
                "    tm_mday  = %d\n"
                "    tm_mon   = %d\n"
                "    tm_year  = %d\n"
                "    tm_wday  = %d\n"
                "    tm_yday  = %d\n"
                "    tm_isdst = %d\n"
                "}\n",
                time_struct.tm_sec,
                time_struct.tm_min,
                time_struct.tm_hour,
                time_struct.tm_mday,
                time_struct.tm_mon,
                time_struct.tm_year,
                time_struct.tm_wday,
                time_struct.tm_yday,
                time_struct.tm_isdst);
    }
    else
        printf("failed to parse\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct tm time_struct;

    std::istringstream iss(argv[1]);
    memset(&time_struct, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    iss >> std::get_time(&time_struct, "%Y-%m-%d");

    print(iss, time_struct);

    std::istringstream iss2(argv[1]);
    memset(&time_struct, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    iss2 >> std::get_time(&time_struct, "%F");

    print(iss2, time_struct);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output. As you can see, the `"%Y-%m-%d"` format works as expected, but the supposedly equivalent `"%F"` does not (it fails to parse).

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
$ ./a.out 2015-09-10
struct tm {
    tm_sec   = 0
    tm_min   = 0
    tm_hour  = 0
    tm_mday  = 10
    tm_mon   = 8
    tm_year  = 115
    tm_wday  = 0
    tm_yday  = 0
    tm_isdst = 0
}
failed to parse
```

Comment: There is no %F modifier in the table here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time

Comment: More info:  The post-Jacksonville C++20 working draft (not available as I write this) will have a `%F` that works with `std::chrono::from_stream` and `std::chrono::parse` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time:

> The format specifiers match the POSIX function strptime()

[Which](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) says nothing about an `%F` specifier.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that [`strftime` has a `%F` specifier since C99 and C++11](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).

However, [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) relates to [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) (in a sense, the opposite function), which [doesn't](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html).

Next time you are unsure, check the documentation.

Comment: the most discreet 'RTFM' I have ever seen

Comment: @pm100: I am well known for my subtlety.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Unfortunately, I was checking the wrong "documentation". www.cplusplus.com [says](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/get_time/) that `std::get_time()` uses the same format specifiers as `std::time_get::get()`, and it [says](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/time_get/get/) that `std::time_get::get()` uses the same specifiers as `strftime()` instead of `strptime()`. Hence my confusion

Comment: Sent an error submission to them so they correct it. Here's to hoping

Comment: @villapx: Good spot! I know that the author is very keen on correcting things like this when found, so I'm sure he'll be happy to have heard from you.

Comment: 3 years and 2 error submissions later, and it's still incorrect :/